how do you rotate specific image layers on a canvas?
I have a canvas that draws a background image and then draws several layers:
context.drawImage(background, 0, 0, width, height);
layers.forEach((layer) => {
  context.drawImage(layer, 0, 0, width, height);
});

I would like to animate rotating the layers, but keeping the background fixed..  I tried doing something like:
animationLoop() {
  const t = document.timeline.currentTime;
  context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
  context.drawImage(background, 0, 0, width, height);
  context.save();
  context.rotate(Math.PI * t);
  layers.forEach((layer) => {
    context.drawImage(layer, 0, 0, width, height);
  });
  context.restore();
  requestAnimationFrame(animationLoop);
}

But that still seems to rotate everything, including the background..  How can I accomplish this?

Please share a runnable [mcve].

If you say that the second snippet in your question does not work then you have not included all the required code needed for us to solve the problem. If the snippet is the ONLY code running then your background would not rotate. I am voting to close

maybe you try running

function animationLoop() {
  const t = document.timeline.currentTime;
  context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
  context.drawImage(background, 0, 0, width, height);
 
 layers.forEach((layer) => {
   context.save();
   context.translate(width / 2, height / 2);
   context.rotate(Math.PI * t);
   context.drawImage(layer, -width / 2, -height / 2, width, height);  
   context.restore();
 });
 
 requestAnimationFrame(animationLoop);
}

animationLoop();


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

I think the bot doesn't like your answer because it's missing a word? "try running/invoking/calling it?"

The bot doesn't like this answer because code-only answers are not good answers. PLease explain how this would solve the issue instead of "try this"
